# how to convert pdf file to Excel file using Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to convert pdf file to Excel using Django, please anyone can help me  how to convert pdf to excel in format way. I  am trying, but the format does not work properly and also how to creating a download link for excel file.
It is possible  to convert pdf to xlxs file in format way in Django ..?
please help how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a web framework, so i suppose your question was that how you can do that in Python. You can use this python library to convert the pdf to excel or CSV
https://pdftables.com/blog/pdf-to-excel-with-python